# How to set timeout while creating connection in ormlite ConnectionSource?

Tags: java, ormlite, connection-timeout

The connection is created by the below method

```
import com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource;
ConnectionSource connectionSource =
    new JdbcConnectionSource(url + databaseName + "?currentSchema=trial&useSSL=false",
            userName, password);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How to set timeout while creating connection in ormlite ConnectionSource?

Right now there is unfortunately no way to set a timeout on the connection.  I would recommend using a database connection pool to give you this functionality.  You can use [Apache's DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi), [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), or [others](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling).

To quote from the docs on [pooled connection sources](https://ormlite.com/docs/pooled-cs):

> There are many other, external data sources that can be used instead, including more robust and probably higher-performance pooled connection managers. You can instantiate your own directly and wrap it in the DataSourceConnectionSource class which delegates to it.
>
> ```
> // basic Apache data source
> BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
> String databaseUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:account";
> dataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
> // we wrap it in the DataSourceConnectionSource
> ConnectionSource connectionSource = 
>    new DataSourceConnectionSource(dataSource, databaseUrl);
> ```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting other options. I would like to know about close method in com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource. Even after closing connection Source attached in Dao object, able to execute query without explicitly creating connection. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The `close()` does not stop future connections to be made @preethisubbu.  It just closes the existing connection.  If you want that behavior then I'd recommend subclassing it and adding that logic.